# Why error "cannot find symbol class out" occur?

Tags: java

I was writing a code in which I print a statement "Hello World" but an error occur named cannot find symbol. I tried hard to remove this error but failed.

```
public class Input{
System.out.println("Hello World");}
```

[This is the statement and the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WiBTc.png)

Please anyone can help me in resolving this error and tell me why this error occur so I will not repeat this mistake in future.

Comment: Place your statement inside a `main` method.

Comment: You need to take a look at how to use [main](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/application/index.html) method inside a class.

Comment: I made another java class in the same package

Comment: java does not allow you to have statements outside functions or static block

Answer (score 1):

Use this :

```
public class Input {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       System.out.println("Hello World");
   }
}
```

You can't print in the scope of a class. You need to inform more about the difference between a function and a class.

Comment: would printing inside of an instance initializer count as printing "in the scope of a class"?

Answer (score 0):

A "class" is sort of like a noun. It's the person, place or thing.

```
public class myThing {
  //This is a comment
  //put stuff that describes the thing in the curly braces
}
```

In order to make the thing do something, you must put it in a method

```
public void myMethod(){
  //code in here gets run when myMethod runs
}
```

Methods must be in a class though. A method can usually be though of as "something a thing can do"

```
public class myThing {
  public void myThingCanDoThis(){
    //does this stuff only when called from somewhere else
  }
}
```

The main method is a special type of method that always looks like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  //This special method gets run automatically when your program runs
}
```

Your hello world should define a thing. It should have the method, or "verb", of "main".

```
public class myThing {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Hello World");
  }
}
```

For now just assume that all your java code must go inside of the main method. Learn the basics and then when you learn more start to pay attention to things like "public", "static", "class" , "void" etc. It will all make sense in time